# Why doesn't the pop up dialog box appears in this turtle graphics

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

This is the code. It is indeed right and I tried the simplest way just to see if a dialog box appears, but still doesn't show up.

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

tim = Turtle()
screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=500, height=400)
tur_name = screen.textinput(title="Who will win?", prompt="Enter the turtle color:")
screen.exitonclick()
```

Comment: dialog box does appear for me.

Comment: Yes, the code is indeed right but doesn't pop up on mine. I guess a bug on my ide.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem... Make sure you are running the right file if you have two files open. This problem happened to me when I had two files open and was running a previous file I was working on rather than the current file I wanted to run.